# Resultado + Agrupamento do resultado MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com uma tremenda duvida em montar essa query que estou anexando, tenho uma tabela e cruzo com uma outra para saber o estado onde teve mais vendas, onde o resultado é agrupado e me mostra o valor total do estado.

Estou querendo trazer o resultado total agrupado pelo estado e em baixo as 5 principais cidades.

Sabendo que na minha tabela tenho os dados, pedido, estado, cidade, valor e etc...

O resultado que tenho atualmente é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o resultado fosse neste outro formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso? Se alguém tiver algum conteúdo para estudo será de grande ajuda.

OBS: Estou utilizando essa query:

```
SELECT controle_uf.estado, alpha.qtd, alpha.vlr, cidade
  FROM (SELECT relat_form_pag_cartao_ods.UF,
               COUNT(relat_form_pag_cartao_ods.Pedido) AS qtd,
               ROUND(SUM(relat_form_pag_cartao_ods.Valor), 0) AS vlr,
               relat_form_pag_cartao_ods.cidade
          FROM relat_form_pag_cartao_ods
         WHERE relat_form_pag_cartao_ods.Data_do_Pedido BETWEEN
               DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
           AND relat_form_pag_cartao_ods.
         Status IN
               ('Aprovado manul', 'Aprovado Automatico', 'Em faturamento')
         GROUP BY relat_form_pag_cartao_ods.uf
         ORDER BY qtd DESC) AS alpha
 RIGHT JOIN controle_uf
    ON controle_uf.uf = alpha.UF
 ORDER BY alpha.vlr DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: cade sua query bro ?

Comment: @David estou utilizando esta query:

Comment: tem que [edit] seu post para adicionar a query

Comment: Acabei de alterar lá na publicação.

Comment: Sinceramente não consegui entender seu exemplo. Pelo que você descreve a primeira linha não deveria conter os totais do estado e as 5 linhas seguintes os totais das 5 cidades deste estado com maior valor? Porque no seu exemplo as cidades aparecem com valores diferentes em "Resultado estado" e "Resultado cidade"?

Comment: Em sua subquery qual o sentido de você colocar cidade em sua lista de seleção se você está agrupando por UF? Ou os nomes dos campos tem significado diferente do usual?

Comment: @anonimo 1 - A ideia da query era trazer o resultado das vendas em geral pela UF ex: SP vendeu 150k, porem em SP tem 1k de cidades, dos 150k em dinheiro vendido no estado de SP, quais são as 5 cidades que mais venderam? Melhor? Os valores da minha tabela criada são ilustrativos.

Comment: @anonimo 2 - Quero agrupar pelo valor total do estado e pelo valor das 5 cidades com mais vendas. (Desculpe minha falta de conhecimento, estou procurando me aprimorar.)

Comment: Seguinte para chegar no resultado que você quer, você terá que fazer um UNION, crie primeiro uma query agrupando os valores por estado, depois crie outra agrupando os valores por cidade... na primeira query no campo cidade não informe nada: select estado, venda, valor, ' ' as cidade, 'Resultado Estado' as tipo_resultado from [conteúdo da query] union select estado, venda, valor, cidade, 'Resultado Cidade' as tipo_resultado from [conteúdo da query] sacou?

Comment: @RaphaelGodoi, acho que entendi o seu ponto, muito obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: Fala @ViitorOliveira poxa fico muito feliz por ter entendido, qualquer dúvida avisa ai :)

Comment: No SQL Server, é muito simples. Já no bendito MySQL terá problemas em usar o `LIMIT` em `sub-query`. Então complica da forma que o @RaphaelGodoi disse.

Comment: Não entendi? Ele nãoo vai precisar usar sub-query... o que estou sugerindo é a criação de union, separando os resultados da forma como ele quer... qual seria a sua sugestão?